# error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Works on one site but not the other

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, iis

So I have two ASP.NET MVC websites deployed to IIS. I have one running on the default website with port 80 and the other website on port 8080. You can connect to both without issues, but when I go to log in to the website on port 8080 it gives me this error.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - 
Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. 
See the Windows Application event log for error details.
```

This only happens on the website on port 8080 and the files on both sites are exactly the same. They are both connecting to the same database that is also hosted on the same computer as these websites.

Connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-DaybreakRecordsArchive-20170113120202.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-DaybreakRecordsArchive-20170113120202;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="daybreakEntities3" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=<username>;password=<pass>;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=cottonwood&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Can you show your connection string?

Comment: I have added the connection strings to the question.

Comment: Please only post the relevant connection string for your error. Don't post unrelated configuration.

Comment: @CameronRodriquez you have MySQL connector installed?

Comment: Well asp.net sites require the top one for account information and the bottom one is my personal database that I'm pulling information from. My guess is that the default connection is the one giving me the issues since it happens when I log in, and the default page does not require anything from my second connection string, although I may be wrong. That is why I included both.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain I have mysql workbench installed which, so far, has given me everything I need. What bothers me is that it works for my default site, but not this second site.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Under "Application Pools" in IIS I had to set the pool for the second website Identity to LocalSystem. It was previously set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. Another issue was that in app-data the .mdf files in there connected to MSSQLLocalDB, but that file name of the .mdf files in App-Data were the same for both sites. I changed the name of the file for one site and fixed the connection string for the corresponding site in web.config. Now they are both working.